# Is it possible to disable the dropdown feature from datalist?

Tags: html, css, html-datalist

I have a text field where the user is supposed to enter a city. The cities are in the form of a datalist selected from my databse. However, I don't want the user to be able to click the little arrow and see a dropdown of all the cities. I only want the cities to show once the user has started typing.

I looked around online and only found a solution to hide the arrow, without disabling it; i.e. if you click where the arrow should be, there is still a dropdown.

Is there anyway to disable this feature altogether?

Answer (score 2):

You could add an event when the `input` receives a click and temporarily remove the `list` attribute. Then on the `keydown` you restore the attribute.

```js
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var input = e.target,
        list = input.getAttribute('list');
    
    if(list) {
        input.setAttribute('data-list', list);
        input.removeAttribute('list');
    }
});

document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    var input = e.target,
        list = input.getAttribute('data-list');

    if(list) {
        input.setAttribute('list', list);
        input.removeAttribute('data-list');
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" list="data">
<datalist id="data">
    <option>10</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the list using Jquery/Javascript is an option.

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="setData()" id="test"/>
```

When user starts typing, have a keyup event and you could check if the length is greater than 1.If so, you can attach the attribute to the input element.

```
function setData() {        
    var data = $("#test").val();
    if (data.length > 1) {
       $("#test").attr('list', 'listname');     //This will add attribute to the input
    } else {
       $("#test").removeAttr('list');         //This will remove the attribute from the input
    }
}
```